# libGDX does not create libs and assets folders

Tags: java, libgdx

Exactly as the title says. To create a libGDX project i use the file "gdx-setup.jar". It launches a nice gui in which i can choose several options.

I set up name, package, android SDK location, the other libraries i need (tools, Box2D...), and eventually i push the "generate" button.

Either i import the project with Eclipse, or i open it with IntelliJ IDEA, some folder is not created. Just in the Android module it is all ok. In the other modules (core, desktop and html), libs and assets folders are missing and i have to create they manually.

Moreover, each time i create a new project, in IntelliJ i have to set up manually the Android SDK!

What's happened?

I didn't have these problems.

Comment: try re-downloading the setup.jar from the official location, which is [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the other projects share the android project's assets folder, so you don't need to create asset folders in the other projects. In IntelliJ when you set up the desktop run configuration, you must set the working directory to the android/assets directory. IIRC, you don't need to do this in Eclipse.

Comment: And does share the other project the libs folder too?

Comment: The libs folder is only for native compiled code used by Android. They are copied out of the library jars during compile because the ADT compiler expects them to be in that location. The other projects build using native compiled code directly from the library jars. And of course, the native code is different for each platform.